# Selecting range on focus quickly gets deselected in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, webkit

I have some javascript which works fine in Chrome/Firefox so that when a user focus's on a contentEditable div, the entire contents get highlighted. In Safari, however, I can see it get highlighted, then quickly the selection get's overridden to where the user clicks.

The following runs in `onFocus`:

```js
const selection = window.getSelection(); // Shouldn't be undefined, but I guess could be?
  if (selection) {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(event.target);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
```

Comment: Try using `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Unfortunaltey, `event.preventDefault()` has no effect.

Comment: @tettoffensive May I ask have you found any workaround/solution for Safari with `window.getSelection()` yet?

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this? It's a total pain in the bottom.